# jquery file select with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code I am trying to check if the file is selected or not from the hyperlink. When the file is selected for the first time the `var fileName = $('#' + field_id).val();` is `null` but when the file is selected for the second time the file path is shown. What is wrong here?

```
<input type="file" id="new_rule_upload" name="new_rule_upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" />
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('new_rule_upload').click(); upload_file('new_rule_upload'); return false">Upload</a>
```

```js
function upload_file(field_id) {
    var fileName = $('#' + field_id).val();
    alert(fileName);
    if (fileName != '') {
        alert('selected')
    } else {
        alert('not selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix up native JS and jQuery. Also, you probably need `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default `<a>` tag behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest attaching yourself to the change event of the input to you can be immediately notified.

```
$(function() {
     $("#new_rule_upload").change(function (){
     var fileName = $(this).val();

     // Do something
   });
});
```

Comment: `$("new_rule_upload")` i guess id/class selector is missing.

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#a_id").click(function() {
        var fileName = $("#new_rule_upload").val();
        alert(fileName);
        if (fileName != '') {
            alert('selected')
        } else {
            alert('not selected');
        }
    });
});
```